# How to get module ancestor in roslyn semanticmodel?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm looking to get ancestor from a module's roslyn semanticmodel.

In a class like this :

```
namespace Name1.Name2
{
    using System;
    ...

    public partial class MyClass : Ancestor<Param1, Param2>
    {
    }
}
```

So I'm trying to get  `Ancestor<Param1, Param2>` (and later `Param1` and `Param2`).

I'm using this code to create the semanticmodel :

```
SyntaxTree tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseFile(moduleAutoGenPath);
CompilationUnitSyntax root = (CompilationUnitSyntax)tree.GetRoot();
var nameSpace = ((NamespaceDeclarationSyntax)(root.Members[0])).Name.ToString();
var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(nameSpace, new[] { tree }).AddReferences(new MetadataFileReference(typeof(object).Assembly.Location));
```

I'm looking on `compilation.Assembly.Modules` but don't find the ancestor..

Am I on the good way? or totally lost?

Comment: What you're looking for are *baseclasses* or *superclasses*, not "module ancestor" (I assume this is terminology you picked up in another language). I'm not sure if you're going the right way, but by visiting any kind of node inside a class you can use this code to get your superclasses: `someNode.Ancestors().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>().FirstOrDefault().BaseList.Types` which I assume you can just turn around if you're looking from the other direction.

Comment: You're right, ancestor is the baseclass.
So if I do `root.DescendantNodes().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>().FirstOrDefault()`
I can take information from the syntaxTree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're trying to get the base class, do this:

```
var classDeclaration = someNode.Ancestors().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>().First();
var semanticModel = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree);
var type = semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(classDeclaration)
```

This gets you the semantic type symbol that represents that syntax. Cast it to ITypeSymbol if it's not already, and access it's BaseType property to get the base type.

As was alluded to in Jeroen's comments: "modules" are totally unrelated things in the .NET world. `compilation.Assembly.Modules` wouldn't have anything related to types. In C#, you can't use syntax to determine a base type, because if you have two partial class declarations, only one of them needs to have the base type. The only "correct" way to do it is with semantics.