# Getting Null for ITypeSymbol

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm writing some tests, and I need to get a ITypeSymbol. Here's how I'm doing it:

```
    private async Task<ITypeSymbol> GetTypeSymbol(string file, TextSpan span)
    {
        var code = File.ReadAllText(file);
        var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(code);

        var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(
            this.GetType().Assembly.GetName().Name,
            syntaxTrees: new[] { tree },
            references: new[]
            {
                MetadataReference.CreateFromAssembly(typeof(object).Assembly))
            });

        var model = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree);
        var root = await tree.GetRootAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        return model.GetTypeInfo(root.FindNode(span)).Type;
    }
```

For some reason, the Type property on the last line is always null, even if I pass in code from a file that looks like this:

```
public class AClass { }
```

To be clear, the file is read fine, it's parsed correctly, the compilation is created, I can get the model, and FindNode() will find the correct ClassDeclarationSyntax node I'm looking for. GetTypeInfo() returns a value, but both Type and ConvertedType are null. I was kind of expecting that this should actually have a value. Is my expectation correct? If so, what am I doing wrong such that the Type property is null?

Comment: To clarify, what I really want to do is find if the type inherits from a certain type, be it an interface or class. If I was able to use reflection, I could do .IsAssignableFrom() and be done, but I can't. So I was going to use BaseType and Interfaces on a ITypeSymbol to do a recursive descent, but if I can't even get the Type from GetTypeInfo() my idea is dead in the water.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it seems like GetDeclaredSymbol() ([How to get module ancestor in roslyn semanticmodel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23650723/how-to-get-module-ancestor-in-roslyn-semanticmodel/)) is the way to go. That works just fine.

Comment: Roslyn generally distinguishes between *declarations* of symbols and *references* to symbols. `GetDeclaredSymbol` is used for the former and `GetSymbolInfo/GetTypeInfo` for the latter.